# How to create a response from a file that has CJK filename

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio, boost-beast

I'm trying to load a file to be a HTTP response with Boost.Beast, but it doesn't work on Windows. My code is similar to this:

```
typedef boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::file_body> response_t;

response_t render_response_from_file(const std::filesystem::path& paFile)
{
    boost::beast::http::file_body::value_type body;
    body.open(paFile.c_str(), boost::beast::file_mode::scan, ec);
    ...
}
```

Method `open` won't be able to find the local file, if the filename contains any CJK character. I've tried to pass `paFile.u8string().c_str()` instead of `paFile.c_str()` as the 1st argument, but in vain. Any suggestion? Thanks.

By the way, on Linux, there is no such problem, because the file-systems on Linux usually use UTF-8 `char` strings to be filenames, not like Windows uses UTF16 `wchar_t` strings. It seems that the conversion to UTF-8 has Windows unable to find the file. However, without the conversion, I don't know if there is any other way to open the file to the `boost::beast::http::file_body::value_type` object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may have been fixed in Boost 1.79.0 - can you give that a try?

For context:

- https://github.com/madmongo1/beast/commit/2c06024aa311d9a39994505d6963244d68916f8a
- https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/2081

Comment: Sorry, I already replaced the file body with a string body in my codes. To change the design, I may have to modify some other codes. Maybe I will try it in other projects in the future. Anyway, I believe a better approach is to have a path object, instead of a c-string, as the argument of the ctor of the file body, which is how Boost.Iostreams works, e.g. the ctor of boost::iostreams::mapped_file. If a boost::filesystem::path is the argument, calling boost::nowide::nowide_filesystem() in advance is enough to deal with the CJK problem.